# ESXi4.1 deleting the first datastore in order to format it with 8m block size

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi server that uses local SATAII disks.

3 datastores.

I have moved all VM's over to the second datastore and there is nothing left on the first datastore.

I removed all VM's from inventory after shutting them down, put server into maintenance mode, rebooted and then attempted to deleted the datastore and I still get the error that the datastore is in use.

I had a look using ssh and on the datastore there is a .locker folder and then 5 .sf files.

any ideas how I can format this datastore?

thanks.

Comment: What version of esxi?

Comment: see subject :)  4.1

Comment: Have you tried it in maintenance mode? You mention that you put the server in maintenance mode, but then rebooted afterwards, presumably exiting form maintenance mode. You should be able to delete it, I've performed the procedure you've described a couple of times, and didn't have any problems.

Comment: yes I tried from maintenance mode. Rebooting does not actually take an ESXi box out of Maintenance mode from my experience but even if it did I tried it. I tried so many things now this is getting frustrating. Thanks though as that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

ESXi automatically creates the first datastore and stores some hidden files/folders for different things like HA and logs.

The only way I've been successful in deleting it is to boot the host with a gparted live cd, and delete the partition. Afterwards ESXi will find a new place for it's files and you can add a new datastore with the 8MB block size.

Standard disclaimer: **WARNING. REMOVING A PARTITION WILL DELETE ANY VMS ON THAT DATASTORE. BACK STUFF UP.**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just did this recently.

Use the vSphere Client interface to work with the datastores. Delete the datastore using the graphical interface, then use "Add Storage" to add a new datastore. You don't have to be in maintenance mode to do this.

Beyond that, I don't know. In my case, the datastore was never used, so I didn't have the problem you're having.